# How to use Ubuntu with read-only file system?

Tags: filesystem, read-only

The question is: what directories of file system I should consider to be mounted as ro (as maximum as possible), and what as rw to use Ubuntu as normal? I want to flash as maximum directories as I can to unerasable ultra-fast storage.
Upgrading and other stuff is not normal :)

Comment: do you have ram on your system ?

Comment: Yes, I have ram (so, I can create a little disk using tmpfs or zram). I just want to make Ubuntu boot from immutable storage. Also, i don't want to use aufs, unionfs or smth. Well, FHS permits some directories to be mounted as readonly, but I cannot find what are they.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it yourself, why not using the live cd of ubuntu ?

Here is a tutorial on how to boot the live cd of ubuntu from the hard drive (in your case your flash drive).

http://www.dangibbs.co.uk/journal/how-to-boot-live-cd-iso-with-grub2-ubuntu

And here is a tutorial on how you can customise a live cd :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Best regards.

Comment: No, I have a really huge piece of software on an immutable storage disk, it can't be fit on a single CD or DVD or USB. The point is, that this storage must be shared between multiple Ubuntu installations. So, I want to install it once, burn to disk, and use multiple machines simultaneously using this storage.

Comment: the physical media has restriction of size but not the iso file :) You can have a 10Gb Iso file if you want. you'll be using only the iso file of the live cd that you'll customise with your software/data.